# Read full matrix in a "Matlab Function"-block in Simulink, not 1 row at a time

Tags: matlab, matrix, simulink, mat

I have a matrix in Simulink (525600 x 2 doubles) about energy consumption per minute.
If i read this matrix with a "From Workspace"-block and use this as an input for a "Matlab Function"-block, it automatically runs the code row per row in the matrix. That way i can't keep the older values and can't get the highest value per 15 minutes.

I have a workaround with the "Delay"-block but i will need 7 of these (see picture).[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdqBS.png)
Is there a better way to do this? I want to read a full matrix in a "Matlab Function"-block.

Comment: Simulink runs as a forward-timestepping simulation, if you read the block description for the `From Workspace` block you'll see that it interprets 2D arrays as being a time column and a data column. You might need to use a struct as detailed in the block description, with a single time value of 0. More generally this sounds like a bit of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), Simulink is not really the best tool for data aggregation e.g. "highest per 15mins", you could just use MATLAB code

Comment: Yes! thank you for your confirmation. I realised this with my mentor (i'm an intern). Good to hear it from someone else too. Thanks!